# how to increase MaxStringContentLength of named pipe?

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I'm using WCF to pass data from one application to another. During execution I receive `System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException`. Inside it .NET claims that MaxStringContentLength should be increased (default value is 8192).

How can I increase MaxStringContentLength of named pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a setting under your binding config

```
<bindings>
 <netNamedPipeBinding>
   <binding name="binding1" ...>
     <readerQuotas
        maxDepth="2147483647"
        maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
   </binding>
```

Comment: thanks, I wrote it in program like that `netNamedPipeBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 65536;` Do you know if I should do that in server, in client or on both sides?

Comment: i've found that at least client should adjust this property. i'm not sure if this need to be done on server.